# Scikitlearn in Jupyter notebook using Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter

This is not a duplicate because the linked question does not address how to either locate the required dlls or fix the installation.

I get the following when I try import sklearn v.0.20. I'm using anaconda and both numpy and scipy are up to date.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8fd979e02004> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn

C:\Users\James2SxyBoogaloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>()
     62 else:
     63     from . import __check_build
---> 64     from .base import clone
     65     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     66 

C:\Users\James2SxyBoogaloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>()
     11 from scipy import sparse
     12 from .externals import six
---> 13 from .utils.fixes import signature
     14 from . import __version__
     15 

C:\Users\James2SxyBoogaloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 13 from .validation import (as_float_array,
     14                          assert_all_finite,
     15                          check_random_state, column_or_1d, check_array,

C:\Users\James2SxyBoogaloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 from ..externals import six
---> 22 from ..utils.fixes import signature
     23 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     24 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning

C:\Users\James2SxyBoogaloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in <module>()
     81             return stats.boxcox(x, lmbda)
     82 else:
---> 83     from scipy.special import boxcox  # noqa
     84 
     85 

    C:\Users\James2SxyBoogaloo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py in <module>()
    638 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    639 
--> 640 from ._ufuncs import *
    641 
    642 from .basic import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: i don't see how the suggested solutions are relevant to this problem?

Comment: How did you install the scikit-learn? Did you try re-installing that?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I found this thread : https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10965

That mentions a problem related to this.

So it seems the guy there solved his problem by removing both numpy and scipy and reinstalling them. There is a chance your version of scipy for some reason is linked against a MLK version of numpy and that's the reason things don't work.

**END OF EDIT**

---

I checked around for your problem and it seems that this is related to the version of numpy you have.

To fix the problem you should install numpy-MLK which is a version on numpy linked against Intel's Math Kernel Library.

You can find it here:
https://pypi.org/project/numpy-mkl/

Just remember to first remove the already existing numpy package.

You can find more info here:

[ImportError when importing certain modules from SciPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480779/importerror-when-importing-certain-modules-from-scipy)

and here:

[Difference between Numpy and Numpy-MKL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513044/difference-between-numpy-and-numpy-mkl)

Comment: That numpy package is very old, I don't think trying to install it is a good idea.

Comment: @Goyo Yes you're right. I'm gonna edit my answer with some more info I found around.