# Importing SciPy or scikit-image, "from scipy.linalg import _fblas: Import Error: DLL failed"

Tags: python, dll, import, scipy, installation

I'm importing:

```
from scipy import misc, io
```

But I get these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\work_asaaki\code\generateProposals.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy import misc, io
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from scipy.special import comb, factorial, factorial2, factorialk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 548, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import orthogonal
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\orthogonal.py", line 90, in <module>
    from scipy import linalg
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 159, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import blas
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 145, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
```

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7, and Python 2.7, In Anaconda's Spyder.
I've tried the following:

```
pip install scipy-stack # this couldn't find any downloads that satisfy scipy-stack
pip install _fblas # this wasn't found
pip install ipython # this was successful
pip install scikit-learn # this was successful
pip install scipy # this was successful
```

I tried downloading SciPy and SciPy-Stack and scitkit-image from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/` but I don't know what's wrong - it seems all the links are broken. My download always fails midway. Is there any way out of this? (Without having to re-install Anaconda Spyder from scratch)?

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: Yes, I just re-downloaded and reinstalled the whole Anaconda/Spyder environment in the end. I couldn't solve it without reinstallation.

Comment: If you look closely on the uci page it mentions "Install numpy+mkl before installing scipy."  this fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 7):

For those who the previous answer doesn't solve the problem, take a look at the answer for this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17511983/1407575

Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem on Windows 8.1 by installing [**Scipy‑stack**‑14.8.27.win32‑py2.7.exe](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy-stack).

Apparently, **scipy‑0.14.0.win32‑py2.7.exe** was missing something.

Comment: Where can I find that file?  It's not linked in the one you provided.

Comment: I'm not a newbie. Of course I used Google. However it turns up nothing. Any alternatives?  Otherwise we may want to close/delete this thread since this answer is no longer helpful.

Comment: In that case, [these are the components of scipy-stack](http://www.scipy.org/stackspec.html). You can download and install them individually.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the similar issue while working with statsmodels package for time series analytics. I am using Anaconda 3.X distribution. May of the answers pointing to install the numpy again form the mkl distribution after uninstalling the regular one.

That might be a good idea but i dont want to disturb my current environment, so i have create a new python virtual environment and installed packages using pip in the following order **numpy>>scipy>>statsmodels**

This did worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and installing of the latest version of NumPy+MKL from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ helped me. By the way, strangely I couldn't install the .whl file via wheel, but installing via pip worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error when I run

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

I solve this by updating scipy from `0.16.0-np110py27_0` to `0.17.1-np110py27_1`

> conda update scipy

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
mkl-11.3.3                 |                1       110.0 MB
python-2.7.12              |                0        23.5 MB
conda-env-2.5.1            |           py27_0          67 KB
ruamel_yaml-0.11.7         |           py27_0         201 KB
conda-4.1.9                |           py27_0         245 KB
numexpr-2.4.4              |      np110py27_0         120 KB
scipy-0.17.1               |      np110py27_1        11.5 MB
scikit-learn-0.16.1        |      np110py27_0         3.5 MB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:       149.1 MB
```

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
mkl:          11.3.3-1
ruamel_yaml:  0.11.7-py27_0
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:        4.0.7-py27_0       --> 4.1.9-py27_0
conda-env:    2.4.5-py27_0       --> 2.5.1-py27_0
numexpr:      2.3.1-np19py27_0   --> 2.4.4-np110py27_0
python:       2.7.11-4           --> 2.7.12-0
scikit-learn: 0.15.2-np19py27_0  --> 0.16.1-np110py27_0
scipy:        0.16.0-np110py27_0 --> 0.17.1-np110py27_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for your Numpy+MKL version [as described here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

This worked for me:

```
python - m pip install xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this solution is working.

window 10 64 bit, Python 3.6.3

1. delete Numpy and Scipy
2. download window binaries of Numpy and Scipy from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
3. install Numpy and Scipy
4. pip3 install scipy-stack

Then, it is working.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

> > conda update scipy

...
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
icc_rt:       2017.0.4-h97af966_0
intel-openmp: 2018.0.0-8
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:        4.3.34-py36_0       conda-forge --> 4.5.0-py36_0
conda-env:    2.6.0-0             conda-forge --> 2.6.0-h36134e3_1
mkl:          2017.0.1-0                      --> 2018.0.2-1
numexpr:      2.6.1-np111py36_2               --> 2.6.4-py36h30784b8_0
numpy:        1.11.3-py36_0                   --> 1.11.3-py36h4a99626_4
pycosat:      0.6.1-py36_1                    --> 0.6.3-py36h413d8a4_0
scikit-learn: 0.18.1-np111py36_1              --> 0.19.1-py36h53aea1b_0
scipy:        0.18.1-np111py36_1              --> 1.0.0-py36h1260518_0
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

To test, I typed
python

> > > from scipy import signal