# Error "from scipy.linalg import _fblas importerror: DLL load failed"

Tags: python-2.7, dll, import, scipy, windows-8.1

I found a code on internet which implement a paper "Effective 3D Action
Recognition Using EigenJoints" [code](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~prashkr/cs365/project/code). They implement in Python so I tried to install Python 2.7.9 and numpy, scipy, scikit-learn. All these libraries installed successfully. In the cmd when i tried to run `python eigen.py` it gives me this [error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzf3ahwpvl8lerd/Capture.PNG?dl=0).
Please anyone download this code and run it by yourself or help me to solve this error.

Comment: Installing packages containing extension modules can be tricky on windows. I would suggest looking into Continuum Analytics' `anaconda` python distribution.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406492/importing-scipy-or-scikit-image-from-scipy-linalg-import-fblas-import-error

Answer (score 0):

You have to do 2 steps:

1. download [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) according to your system and specifications.
2. Make sure that Anaconda is installed on python version installed on your system. For example, if you have python 3.4, and anaconda in installled on 2.7, then you should remove python 3.4.

Afterwards, the code will run smoothly and all libraries will be well defined. I have made the same ;) Please, let me know if you face new problems.

Comment: user: thank you very much for your reply. I have Python 2.7.9 installed on my PC and the acaconda in 2.7.8, so is it correct????

Comment: I guess it will work fine. Did you face problems ? the libraries are not defined ?

Comment: I dont know how to run the code in Anancode after that. Do I have to open Anaconda Command prompt? Could you tell me in steps how can i run the code in Anaconda and install libraries?

Comment: No need for anaconda command prompt. (1) install anaconda from the mentioned url. (2) make sure your python version is the same of the one with anaconda (just type python --version) (3) it has numpy, scipy, Cython and everything. Tell me which IDE do you use ?

Comment: 1) Yes, I downloaded and installed the anaconda from the link you mentioned above-- (DONE)  2) Anaconda version is 2.7 and my python installed version is 2.7.9. Now, how can I start running my code in anaconda?

Comment: I am using spyder. in the command prompt -> goto anaconda directory and typed Spyder and it run. is it correct?

Comment: You don't start running your code in anaconda :)
Briefly, anaconda is a big librariy, which contains some sub-libraries used in python, for example numpy. The code of Eigen joints you have downloaded is 2 python classes, and they use these sub-libraries. So once, you install anaconda, then the sub-libraries are defined and you can run the eigen joints code properly. It is clear now ? feel free to get back to me.