# Scipy BLAS error

Tags: python, scipy, blas

I recently updated numpy from 1.7.1 to 1.10.1 and scipy from 0.15.1 to 0.16.1 and now I get the error below when I run code that involved scipy:

```
  File "C:\Python27_x64\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried all this:

- fully reinstall Python 2.7.10
- install numpy and scipy from whl files (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)
- install numpy and scipy from pip
- install numpy+mkl, as suggested here: [ImportError when importing certain modules from SciPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480779/importerror-when-importing-certain-modules-from-scipy)

But none of these worked. I followed the address and found the missing module at the specified path in the python folder.
I'm using Python 2.7.10 on Win-64 bit with PyCharm code editor.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

They have been removed.  From the `scipy` 0.16.0 [release notes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.16.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes):

> The following deprecated modules have been removed: `scipy.lib.blas`, `scipy.lib.lapack`, `scipy.linalg.cblas`, `scipy.linalg.fblas`, `scipy.linalg.clapack`, `scipy.linalg.flapack`. They had been deprecated since Scipy 0.12.0, the functionality should be accessed as `scipy.linalg.blas` and `scipy.linalg.lapack`.

Comment: But what do I do if the lines are called by another package? In my chase they are called by scikit-image.

Comment: You need to see if there is an update to the package, or downgrade scipy.

Comment: The scikit-image module is updated, so, how do I downgrade scipy? I tried -> 'pip install scipy == 0.15.1'

Comment: This is not the issue: look at the error message. Rather, it's likely about the C++ runtimes (please carefully read the text at the top of the page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score -3):

I solved it by uninstalling Python 2.7.10 and installing the Anaconda distribution.

https://www.continuum.io/downloads