# Can not import scipy.misc

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to do

```
from scipy.misc import imread
```

and I am getting the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Uname\Documents\Py\test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.misc import imread
  File "C:\Users\Uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from scipy.special import comb, factorial, factorial2, factorialk
  File "C:\Users\Uname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 627, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

I am using Python 3.5 in Windows and have installed scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy. I have checked other solutions available but nothing worked for me

Installed python modules

```
cv2 (1.0)
cycler (0.10.0)
dask (0.8.1)
decorator (4.0.9
Django (1.9.5)
matplotlib (1.5.
networkx (1.11)
numpy (1.11.0)
Pillow (3.2.0)
pip (8.1.1)
pyparsing (2.1.1
python-dateutil
pytz (2016.3)
scikit-image (0.
scipy (0.17.0)
setuptools (18.2
six (1.10.0)
toolz (0.7.4)
```

Comment: Does the answer here work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17511983/1612744

Comment: Thanks it worked after installing Visual C++ 2015(x64 and x86)