# scipy.interpolate leads to ImportError

Tags: python, scipy

my setup is

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I have scipy `0.17` and cartopy '0.14.2'.

All I'm trying to do is

```
plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

and it leads to this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-93-636aeb1a7fc6>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 867, in axes
    return subplot(111, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1022, in subplot
    a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 987, in add_subplot
    self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/projections/__init__.py", line 100, in process_projection_requirements
    projection_class, extra_kwargs = projection._as_mpl_axes()
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cartopy/crs.py", line 150, in _as_mpl_axes
    import cartopy.mpl.geoaxes as geoaxes
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py", line 52, in <module>
    from cartopy.vector_transform import vector_scalar_to_grid
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cartopy/vector_transform.py", line 26, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate import griddata
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/__init__.py", line 158, in <module>
    from .interpolate import *
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 12, in <module>
    import scipy.special as spec
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py", line 629, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "/opt/pycharm-2016.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda2/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/special/basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import (ellipkm1, mathieu_a, mathieu_b, iv, jv, gamma, psi, zeta,
ImportError: cannot import name 'zeta'
```

Deep down this appears to be a scipy problem, but I have the newest there - what's going on here?

Comment: Can you also add an explicit `from scipy import interpolate,signal,special` before the import statements just to check?

Comment: @percusse That leads to the same `ImportError`.

Comment: Then probably your scipy installation is problematic. Could you please check what is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480779/importerror-when-importing-certain-modules-from-scipy ?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a problem with the `scipy` installation coming from `conda`. Creating a new environment and freshly installing `scipy` solved the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this topic? I'm having the same problem to use the library ray-optics