# I cant run seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, seaborn

Hi I am currently trying to use seaborn but I can't because every time I try to run just

```
import seaborn as sns
```

I get this output

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mikele/Desktop/Python/Testuju sracky.py", line 2, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .rcmod import *
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import palettes, _orig_rc_params
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .utils import desaturate, set_hls_values, get_color_cycle
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py", line 6, in <module>
    from scipy import stats
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
    from .stats import *
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 179, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    from ._procrustes import procrustes
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_procrustes.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import orthogonal_procrustes
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 195, in <module>
    from .misc import *
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs
  File "C:\Users\mikele\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 215, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module was not found
```

I am using windows 10 and I am programming in pycharm

Thank you for your responses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError when importing certain modules from SciPY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480779/importerror-when-importing-certain-modules-from-scipy)

Comment: Not really I tried all of it and nothing worked